# Woocommerce error with adding any address to cart page, loading/ spinner

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

so as soon as you add an address to the woocommerce cart page, the spinner comes up and will not go away. Ive checked the console, and disabled the "smart velocity minify" plugin from combining js, tried disabling plugin after plugin but nothing seems to help?

Can anyone tell what is causing the issue on this page? or a good way to trouble shoot this?

Add this product to cart : https://www.subscriptionboxaustralia.com/product/miscellaneous-subscription-boxes/test-product/

attempt to checkout using any Australian address : 10 main rd, paynesville, victoria 3880

The spinner/ loading will start, and never stops, thus not letting the customer check-out

Thanks Guys

Comment: p.s im not using any other caching, except for CloudFlare which i purged and put into development mode for the testing of this issue

Comment: Hey,
I tested and theres no JS errors.... Are there any error in your error log? usually found at your root dir called error.log.
On first look I'd say it looks like a conflict with stripe.

Comment: @WilliamTurner thanks for taking a look mate, means alot,

Well i checked the woocommerce logs, no errors logged today.
I turned wp-debug to true, and checked those logs, nothing there either, or in my error.log in my root dir. Painful…..

Comment: wow super weird, once i disabled “BIALTY – Bulk Image Alt Text (Alt tag, Alt Attribute) with Yoast SEO + WooCommerce” all seems to be working fine now? this was the last plugin i would suspect, but it seems to have done the trick, ill do a bit more testing before i declare this fixed, but its looking good =)

Comment: Howd your testing go? Gonna assume you found the issue! 
Always the ones you least expect ;)